# AG Grid valueGetter + Pagination

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag grid (angular2) for rendering table and uses valueGetter feature to render row data to ui.

I would like to add onscroll pagination to my ui, but couldn't find a way to use datasource.

```
`gridOptions.api.setDatasource(ds);`
```

How to collaborate valueGetter and pagination here?

**valueGetter code**

```
this.gridData  = {cols:["col1", "col2"], rows:[["data1","data2"],
["data3","data4"]]};
this.columnDefs = [];
this.rowData = this.gridData.rows;
for (var i in this.gridData.cols){
  var scopeOutCurrIndex = i => (params) => params.data[i]
  this.columnDefs.push({
    headerName: this.gridData.cols[i],
    valueGetter: scopeOutCurrIndex(i)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward, one can use the same implementation to achieve this:

```
 var dataSource = {
        data: gData,
        rowCount: null,
        getRows: function (params) {
            console.log("asking for " + params.startRow + " to " + params.endRow);
            var rowsThisPage = this.data.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
            var lastRow = -1;
            if (this.data.length <= params.endRow) {
                lastRow = this.data.length;
            }
            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }
    };

    this.gridApi.setDatasource(dataSource);
```